# Trouble in getting contact's phone numbers by contact id

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

Here is my code to get data of user from phone's database:

```
Uri contactDataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    /*final String[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
    };*/

    final String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id;

    Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(
            contactDataUri,
            null,
            selection,
            null,
            null
    );
    //contactCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {


        contactName = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));

        //Getting phone numbers

        if (contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype"))
                .equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "contact id " + id + "has phones", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (contactCursor.getInt(contactCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))) {
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                    homePhone = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                    Toast.makeText(context, "contact id " + id +"has homePhone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    mobilePhone = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                    workPhone = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    contactCursor.close();
    TextView cname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    cname.setText(contactName);

    TextView cnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_number);
    if (!homePhone.equals("") && homePhone != null) {
        cnum.setText(homePhone);
        number = homePhone;
    } else if (mobilePhone != null && !mobilePhone.equals("")) {
        cnum.setText(mobilePhone);
        number = mobilePhone;
    } else if (workPhone != null && !workPhone.equals("")) {
        cnum.setText(workPhone);
        number = workPhone;
    } else {
        cnum.setText("No number found!");
        contact_call = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_call);
        contact_call.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        contact_call.setClickable(false);
    }
```

I am getting information of contactName perfactly, however I am facing trouble in getting information of contact's stored phone numbers. 
After putting toast I came to know that the IF condition contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype"))
                    .equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
is where I'm having some trouble.
I need to get contact's numbers from fetched id. So any other mEthod to get phone number will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: tried `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(contactCursor)` ?

Comment: replace: `if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {` with: `while (contactCursor.moveToNext()) {`

Comment: @pskink thanks, it worked :)

Comment: You should also add MIMETYPE equal to PHONE.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE to the selection to query only the phone numbers.